# Concrete patio slopes toward garage causing water seepage

Tags: concrete, drainage, patio, grading

As indicated in inspection report photo my concrete patio slopes toward the garage so when there’s heavy rain water seeps into the garage. Is installing a French drain the only way to fix this or is there another option? Not thrilled about having to jackhammer the concrete and repour after for French drain. Same problem on the driveway near the garage door but less so. [image]

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is to cut the concrete and dig a trench for a drain between the patio and the door.  As long as the water isn't too much to overflow that drain, it will work.

But if your water problem is too much for such a drain, and I suspect it may be, the real solution is to remove the slab, grade the ground away from the garage, and then re-pour the slab.

Yes, that's a lot of work but it's the only one that is a sure-fire solution to the problem.  Having water run back toward your home is a recipe for long-term damage.  So you'll be better off all around fixing it right and not having to worry about it again.